# Changing user for supervisor - error CRIT Set uid to user

Tags: bash, logs, configuration, root, supervisord

I changed user for supervisor from root to non-root called dev.

All is good, supervisor is running as dev:

```
me@server$ ps aux | grep supervisor
dev  25230  0.2  1.0  60404 21392 ?        Ss   21:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

...but logs shows this message:

```
Nov 15 21:45:00 server supervisord[25473]: 2019-11-15 21:45:00,880 CRIT Set uid to user 1003
```

This is uid for user dev:

```
me@server$ id dev
uid=1003(dev) gid=1000(ww) groups=1000(ww)
```

What does it mean? How should I change uid when user with this uid is already running supervisor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#supervisord-section-values), you have to start supervised as root, and let her drop privileges.

Current version logs the user change like `Set uid to user dev succeeded`

Probably you are using some older version, if you upgrade for current, this misleading log message will disappear. For now, you can safely ignore it.

[Here is the github commit for the mentioned change/fix](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/commit/e536fb1f03697135cd3be961aa5c5c715aab6423)

Comment: Ok, so nothing to worry about. Thanks! Btw. I also found this usefull: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/693